# C++ Regex to grab IP from specific line

Tags: c++, regex

I'm working on a C++ program that needs to collect IPs from **standard** Nmap output.  I can't use the -oX, -oG, or -oA flags for reasons that I'd rather not explain.  I have the following regex:

```
std::regex IPRegex("^Nmap scan report for ([\\S]*\\s\\()?(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3})");
```

I simply want to grab all the IPs from that specific line of nmap output.  However, sometimes they are preceded by the DNS name and closed in parenthesis, and sometimes they are not, thus the first optional capture group in my regex.  I also recognize that with C++, I need to double backslashes to escape regex tokens/string literals.

Example nmap output:

```
Nmap scan report for mycomputer.mydomain (192.168.1.1)
Host is up (0.00013s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
8080/tcp open  http-proxy

Nmap scan report for mycomputer2.mydomain (192.168.1.2)
Host is up (0.0085s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on mycomputer2.mydomain (192.168.1.2) are closed

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.3
Host is up (0.0057s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on 192.168.1.3 are closed
```

The idea is that I should be able to extract exactly the IPs I want using just

```
std::sregex_iterator IPIter(output.begin(), output.end(), IPRegex);
std::sregex_iterator end;
while (IPIter != end) {
  std::smatch match = *IPIter;
  IPList += match.str(2);         // Testing with match.str(0) had no matches at all either
  IPIter++;
}
```

But I get no regex matches at all.  I tested this using regex101.com, the only difference being that I used single backslash escapes, and it worked fine.  I can't troubleshoot where the problem is doing the same thing in my C++ program.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a multiline string, replace `^` with `(?:^|\n)`

Comment: Use raw string literals for regexes, avoids the slashes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew tried it, but no effect.  That also wouldn't explain how I still get no matches for any of the shorter lines.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I've tried just about every combination I can think of both with and without double/single slashes.

Comment: It looks like your problem is elsewhere, [my suggestion works](https://ideone.com/jYGsbc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. Just use the following regexp:

```
Nmap scan report for .*\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b
```

You don't need to match things like the domain name and parentheses specifically, just skip over them with `.*`. You're not processing general text input, so there won't be any false positives from being less precise. `Nmap scan report` won't appear anywhere other than the beginning of lines, so you don't actually need to match `^`.

Comment: That did it!  Turns out my newlines were getting consumed somehow during the process of reading in the output.  Took away the '^' and it worked fine.  Thank you!